# How to write a function in bash?

Tags: bash, test

I am drawing blank here.  How should I have written this script?

```
#!/bin/sh

XZY_NODES="\
vl-ocnt-1 \
vl-ocnt-2 \
vl-onet-1 \
vl-onet-2 \
vl-ocmp-1 \
vl-oomp-2 \
"

is_xyz_node () {
        host=$1
        for xyznode in $XZY_NODES
        do
                if [ $host == $xyznode ]
                then
                        return 'Y'
                fi
        done
        return 'N'
}

if [ 'Y' == $(is_xyz_node $1) ]
then
        echo "$1 is a xyz node"
else
        echo "$1 is NOT a xyz node"
fi
```

When I run this script I get this output ...

```
$ ./test.sh not-xyz
./test.sh: line 22: return: N: numeric argument required
./test.sh: line 25: [: Y: unary operator expected
not-xyz is NOT a xyz node

$ ./test.sh vl-ocnt-2
./test.sh: line 19: return: Y: numeric argument required
./test.sh: line 25: [: Y: unary operator expected
vl-ocnt-2 is NOT a xyz node
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your code a bit:

```
is_xyz_node() {
  host="$1"
  for xyznode in $XZY_NODES; do
    if [ -n "$xyznode" ] &&
       [ "$host" = "$xyznode" ]; then
      return 0
    fi
  done
  return 1
}

if is_xyz_node "$1"; then
  printf '%s is a xyz node\n' "$1"
else
  printf '%s is NOT a xyz node\n' "$1"
fi
```

There are some things to note:

- `return` in bash requires an integer type in its optional argument; it causes the function to exit with that integer as its status or with the value of `$?` if it is not provided. So you must use an integer instead of a string. The integer must be between 0 and inclusive; `return 0` mean success, any other value means failure.
- You should protect your variables by wrapping them in double quotes.
- You should add a test that `$xyznode` is not null. As @mikeserv point out in his comment, it's possible that both `$1` and `$xyznode` are null string, so `[ '' = '' ]` return true.

Answer (score 4):

Return needs to be an integer, so `1` or `0`. In `bash`, `false` would be `1` and `true` would be `0`. So I would replace `'N'` with `1` and `'Y'` with `0`

Also, then you would also change the `if` statement as you would no longer be matching against `'Y'`, you would be matching against `0`.

```
if [ 'Y' == $(is_xyz_node $1) ]
```

should become

```
if is_xyz_node $1
```

as the function should return `1` or `0` which corresponds to `true` or `false`.

Comment: In `bash`, return `0` means success, otherwise fail.

Comment: @Gnouc you are correct, sorry. Got mixed up :)